# How to read directory -> read content of all files found -> and content to a "if" statements

Tags: php, if-statement

this is my first question after being an avid reader of this site for a while now.

I have a php script that queries my database, and inside of that I have an if statement to allow only certain categories to show up in results.

I am building a script that will allow people to query my database, the script and service will be free, but I would like to be able to open up certain categories for searching by charging a really small fee just to help with server costs. And the best way I can think of doing this is above, by allowing them to purchase a file, placing that file in a certain folder, and have the script automatically know its there and open up a category. Ive never done anything like this before.

Basically the if statement goes like this:

```
if ($cat == 'Apple' || $cat == 'Orange'){  
    $returnval = $1 . "|" . $2 . "|" . $3 . "|" . $cat;  
}
```

$1 $2 $3 $cat being what I queried.

My question is:

How can I make this if statement dynamic, by reading unknown files located in a directory? Say if each file inside of it `$cat=='Apple'` and after each file read a `||` was placed after it unless the last file found.

What kind of php code would read a directory, then read all contents, making sure it was formatted as `$cat=='Apple'` otherwise ignore, placing `||` at the end of contents that match that format, adding the contents to a string, placing it into that if statement above?

I think Im explaining what I would like to learn how to do right, but maybe there is another way.

The reason I want to do this, is because I would like to add functionality to a script I made, based on files located in a certain folder, each file adding functionality just by being in that directory.

Is this possible? Or is there maybe a better way?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Not sure what you're trying to do here. But I would suggest you have the category information (what is queriable and access levels) inside the file itself so that the code will run if the file is there or serve up your default site. Also, you might want to look at Access Control Lists.

Comment: Thank you, Im glad i finally had a question to ask! lol Seems like they were all already answered :). I was thinking about that, I just have qround 50 cats that I want to limit, and I couldnt think of an easy way to code that without making the actual script really large in size. Im def gonna look into this though. TY  Also I am worried about the future, if cats get deleted or added from my server, it will be hardcoded in the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really add code to your code with code, but you can use other methods that accomplish the same thing. Mostly, you're probably looking for arrays:

```
if (in_array($cat, array('Apple', 'Orange', ...))
```

http://php.net/in_array

As for people purchasing files on your server... There's gotta be a better solution than this, but you'd need to lay out your plans a little better for that to be answerable. Usually anything like that would only involve database queries, not files.

Comment: I wish I was more experienced in controlled information, most of what i do i just let it be wide open and free, but in this case I really need to charge a small fee. My thought about the files is that it would just be an easy way to "unlock a category" By creating that if statement that only allows what i put in it stock.  Am I thinking about this in the right way? I really dont want to go with userlists or keeping track of users, permissions etc. Have you seen anything like this before? Thanks for your input

Comment: @John You *want* to identify users and give them different permissions based on who they are, yet you *don't* want to handle users?

Comment: Not that I refuse to, I just want the process to be as easy as purchasing the file for a category and them placing it in the folder and have the category activated. Or similar, I know it sounds different maybe even stupid, but Im hoping someone has done this or knows how it could be done.

Comment: @John Don't think about it in terms of "user purchases a file". You need to decouple that a bit. You want the user to give you money, which is a piece of information you're going to store somewhere, and based on that information you're going to enable some feature for the user. Having the user deal with files sounds like unnecessary implementation details the user shouldn't be concerned about.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want the contents of a directory, then you can compare from there.  `glob()` accomplishes this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

As for user charging, I'd highly suggest you pursue a login type system, I'm not sure of the context in which your database operates, but if it's HTTP accessed, create an html page with `<input>` types to collect username/password to validate that the user had the rights to access these categories.

If your context is RESTful, you can have the user information encoded on the url, I know the BestBuy RESTful API does this.